# inAppBrowser window reference cordova when window opened by 3rd party script

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Is there a way to get a reference to the `inAppBrowser` window when the window is being opened by a 3rd party Javascript that I do not have control over?

This currently launches properly in the `inAppBrowser`. I just don't how/if I can reference it so that I can add `addEventListeners`.

This is how they are opening the popup:

```
  function launchPopupDirectly() {
        if (popup && !popup.closed) {
            return false;
        }
        var name = '';
        var url = configuredOptions.domain + '/index.php?rm=box_select_view';
        url += '&client_id=' + configuredOptions.clientId;
        url += '&link_type=' + configuredOptions.linkType;
        url += '&multiselect=' + configuredOptions.multiselect;
        var specs = 'height=' + windowConfiguration.height + ',width='
                + windowConfiguration.width;
        popup = window.open(url, name, specs);
        detectPopupClose();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can bind `addEventListener` to `popup`. Like so

```
function launchPopupDirectly() {
    if (popup && !popup.closed) {
         return false;
     }
     var name = '';
     var url = configuredOptions.domain + '/index.php?rm=box_select_view';
     url += '&client_id=' + configuredOptions.clientId;
     url += '&link_type=' + configuredOptions.linkType;
     url += '&multiselect=' + configuredOptions.multiselect;
     var specs = 'height=' + windowConfiguration.height + ',width='
               + windowConfiguration.width;
     popup = window.open(url, name, specs);
     //Modification here
     popup.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { 
        alert('Browser loaded '+event.url); 
     });

     detectPopupClose();
     return true;
}
```

Here is the list of events you can listen for:

- **loadstart:** event fires when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL.
- **loadstop:** event fires when the InAppBrowser finishes loading a URL.
- **loaderror:** event fires when the InAppBrowser encounters an error when loading a URL.
- **exit:** event fires when the InAppBrowser window is closed.

Reference: InAppBrowser Documentation http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#addEventListener

Comment: I should have made it more clear that I don't have control over function launchPopupDirectly(). I included that function to show how the 3rd party is opening the window.

Comment: The only way you can control the IAP is by plugging into `popup` directly. When you say you don't have control over the function, what do you mean? Are you operating on another layer of the HTML document? Through an iframe or something?

Comment: I have a similar situation. We have a hybrid app that uses an authentication service that injects the code it uses to launch the in app browser, so we do not have the option to tack on the event listener. But, it appears that there is not a way to do it.